# Итоговая сумма на всех строках PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery

подскажите пожалуйста, как посчитать столбец "Итого по категории" формулой в PowerQuery?
Важен именно такой формат таблицы, т.е. чтоб значение "Итого по категории" прописывалось в каждую категорию и подкатегорию (без свертывания)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо